# SQL Trigger doesn't execute triggers procedure

Tags: sql-server, triggers

In SQL management studio I want to add trigger to one table. When data is inserted into table I want to insert or update data in other tables if some requirements are met.

```sql
ALTER trigger [dbo].[game_data_received]
on [dbo].[GameRounds]
for insert
as

declare @LastDate datetime
declare @CurrDate datetime
declare @GameID int
declare @TimeDiff int
declare @CurrMult int
declare @MaxMult int
declare @MaxDiff int

select @GameID = i.GameID from inserted i
select @CurrDate = i.[TimeStamp] from inserted i
select @CurrMult = i.MaxMultiplier from inserted i
select @LastDate = max([TimeStamp]) from GameRounds where GameID = @GameID

select @TimeDiff = DATEDIFF(SECOND, @LastDate, @CurrDate)
select @MaxDiff = (select TimeDifference from AcceptableTimeDiffGameRounds where GameID = @GameID)
select @MaxMult = (select MaxMultiplier from AcceptableTimeDiffGameRounds where GameID = @GameID)

if @TimeDiff > @MaxDiff
    if @CurrMult >= @MaxMult    
        update AcceptableTimeDiffGameRounds
        set MaxMultiplier = @CurrMult, TimeDifference = @TimeDiff
        where GameID = @GameID
            
    else    
        insert into Defects(DownFrom, DownUntill)
        values (@LastDate, @CurrDate)
```

So this is my trigger query. Data in the GameRounds table are inserted automaticaly, but it doesn't executes this whole procedure. I can tell this because, when I select the tables where data should be added or change they stay same. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Triggers don't fire on single records since there can be multiple inserted records.  So unfortunately you can't treat the variables in your trigger as if they're single values.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server is a SET-based language and the best practice is to handle it as such.

A commom misconception with triggers is that they're only responsible for 1 row, however, an insert trigger could have 1 or thousands of rows. The trigger you shared only handles a single inserted record (last in)--not all of them.

While I would not recommend handling your request this way--it really should be written to handle the entire inserted rowset at once--I have had to process an insert row-by-agonizing-row (RBAR) in the past. In this case, you could try rewriting your trigger like the following:

```
DECLARE @GameID int, @CurrDate datetime, @CurrMult int, @row_id int = 1;
DECLARE @inserted_rows table (
    GameID int, CurrDate datetime, CurrMult int, row_id int IDENTITY ( 1, 1 )
);

INSERT INTO @inserted_rows (
    GameID, CurrDate, CurrMult
)
SELECT
    GameID, [TimeStamp], MaxMultiplier
FROM inserted;

WHILE @row_id <= ( SELECT MAX ( row_id ) FROM @inserted_rows )
BEGIN

    -- Current row.
    SELECT
        @GameID = GameID, @CurrDate = CurrDate, @CurrMult = CurrMult
    FROM @inserted_rows WHERE row_id = @row_id;

    -- Process row.

    DECLARE @MaxMult int, @MaxDiff int;
    DECLARE @LastDate datetime = ( SELECT MAX( [TimeStamp] ) FROM GameRounds WHERE GameID = @GameID );
    DECLARE @TimeDiff int = DATEDIFF( second, @LastDate, @CurrDate);

    SELECT
        @MaxMult = MaxMultiplier,
        @MaxDiff = TimeDifference 
    FROM AcceptableTimeDiffGameRounds
    WHERE 
        GameID = @GameID;

    IF @TimeDiff > @MaxDiff
    BEGIN

        IF @CurrMult >= @MaxMult    
            UPDATE AcceptableTimeDiffGameRounds
            SET 
                MaxMultiplier = @CurrMult,
                TimeDifference = @TimeDiff
            WHERE GameID = @GameID;

    END            
    ELSE
    BEGIN

        INSERT INTO Defects ( DownFrom, DownUntill )
            VALUES ( @LastDate, @CurrDate );

    END

    -- Next row.
    SET @row_id = @row_id + 1;

END
```

This example captures all of the inserted rows and then processes them one at a time (without using a cursor)--which can be painfully slow, not to mention locking issues.

Ideally, you would rewrite this using a set-based approach.